# Java TCP SSL sockets - How does the server keep me waiting?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, inputstream, readline

I am composing my own client to communicate with an existing server, using some uncommon protocol.
The protocol is basically to send and receive XML chunks over a TLS 1.2 TCP socket.
It describes quite long sessions. Sometimes, client and server will send and receive XML's for weeks without disconnecting.

I don't understand how my client is patiently waiting for stuff to be sent, even when the server isn't sending.

When connecting to the server, I am getting something like:

```
<mainTag>
<greeting>
</greeting>
(notice: no </mainTag>)
```

Nothing in my client implements a logic of `"if you see <tag>, wait for </tag>"` (I've written it all myself, from scratch).

Here's some of my code regarding how I read stuff sent from the server:

```
try (
    SSLSocket socket = getSSLsocket(keystoreFile, keystorePass, keystorePass);
        // ... Write-stuff removed, irrelevant to the question ...
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        socket.startHandshake();
        // ... Write-stuff removed, irrelevant to the question ...
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
}

private static SSLSocket getSSLsocket (String ksPath, String ksPass, String pkPass) {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        // ... Some key management stuff removed ...
    SSLSocketFactory sslScktFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    return (SSLSocket)sslScktFactory.createSocket(hostFQDN, port);
}
```

In particular, during debugging, I am stepping into: `while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)` and I reach `</greeting>` but when I step-into again, I can see it's just hanging there.

Is `.readLine()` returning something? if so, why isn't it printed?
Or, it's not returning something? if so, why isn't `.readLine()` null?

Comment: This is just how blocking I/O works. The thread simply waits to receive the input (in this case some text terminated with any newline character(s)) or until an exception is thrown. You would need to provide the server code to diagnose why the last closing tag isn't sent.

Comment: yeah, that thought occurred to me just now. When I look closely, I can see the server is also sending the number of bytes to read. It's so embarrassing. I hate being stupid.

Comment: I hate being stupid too. It's just something we learn to live with ... and occasionally curese at :)